# How to increase SQL execution timeout for a stored procedure in .Net

Tags: sql-server, timeout, dapper

I need to increase the timeout on this stored procedure's execution to 90 secs (default is 30).

```cs
using (var conn = db.GetOpenConnection())
{
     data = conn.Query<DataPoint>(
         @"dbo.sp_xxxxxxxx",
         parameters,
         commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure
       ).ToList();
}
```

Can you suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like, you are using [Dapper](http://dapper-tutorial.net/query). You can pass `commandTimeout: 90` as parameter to `query` method to overwrite default setting.

```
using (var conn = db.GetOpenConnection())
{
  data = conn.Query<DataPoint>(
  @"dbo.sp_xxxxxxxx", parameters,  
  commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 90).ToList();
}
```

Comment: @rads - you can mark it as answer if it resolves your issue.